# Could I expect any adverse reactions with this ink mix?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

Our newest R&D project for a permanent, outdoor ink includes:

- $\pu{25 g}$ of solvent blue 70.
- $\pu{25 g}$ of nigrosene.
- $\pu{??? g}$ of silver nitrate in a denatured alcohol base.
- Several "natural" binders of the shellac variety as well.

My question really has to do with the silver nitrate. I've never had the chance to experiment with it, so I'm coming to the experts to make sure it's safe enough to at least try.

Answer (score 3):

Adding silver nitrate to any mixture or solution will produce a solution that will slowly turn grey-black and irregular permanent grey-black, due to the effect of sunlight. This effect will occur on all places were the smallest drop of silver nitrate was in contact, everywhere, and even on the skin or trousers. So silver nitrate is safe, but the dark spots due to silver are more or less dark grey-black and irregularly distributed.